# mod_wsgi forbidden error on CentOS 5.7

Tags: python, apache, centos, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I know that this question was asked millions of times, but i already spent many hours trying to configure Apache and mod_wsgi on CentOS 5.7, which it new to me. Never faced this kind of problem on Debian (Ubuntu).

I've created `wsgi.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` directory, containting the following lines:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /var/xxx/env
```

`/var/xxx/env` contains virtual environment for the project.

Then I've added the following lines into `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` (yes, I need it for https, but i also tried to put it into normal virtual host).

```
WSGIScriptAlias /suburl /var/xxx/yyy/hello.wsgi
<Location /suburl>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

`hello.wsgi` contains

```
def application(environ, start_response):
       status = '200 OK'
       output = 'Hello World!'
       response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
              ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
       start_response(status, response_headers)
       return [output]
```

Here is the output of `ls -l /var/xxx/`

```
 total 16
 drwxr-xr-x 5 apache apache 4096 Feb  9 05:14 env
 drwxr-xr-x 7 apache apache 4096 Feb  9 05:41 yyy
```

and output of `ls -l /var/xxx/yyy/`

```
total ...
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache  238 Feb  9 05:19 hello.wsgi
...
```

`ps -Af | grep httpd` shows

```
 root      8872     1  0 07:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 apache    8874  8872  0 07:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 apache    8875  8872  0 07:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 apache    8876  8872  0 07:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 apache    8877  8872  0 07:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 apache    8878  8872  0 07:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 apache    8879  8872  0 07:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 apache    8880  8872  0 07:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 apache    8881  8872  0 07:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
 fedor    10609  4716  0 07:16 pts/1    00:00:00 grep httpd
```

`/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log` is full of lines like the following

```
[Thu Feb 09 07:06:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /suburl denied
```

BUT it start Apache by calling `sudo /usr/sbin/httpd` hello.wsgi starts working, even though `ps -Af | grep httpd` shows very similar lines:

```
root     11442     1  3 07:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   11443 11442  0 07:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   11444 11442  0 07:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   11445 11442  0 07:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   11446 11442  0 07:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   11447 11442  0 07:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   11448 11442  0 07:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   11449 11442  0 07:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   11450 11442  0 07:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
fedor    11453  4716  0 07:21 pts/1    00:00:00 grep httpd
```

Any ideas what may cause the problem and what else do i have to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the appropriate SELinux file context on the files and directories. See the `httpd_selinux(8)` man page for details.

Comment: Thank you for help. After I've done `sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t /var/xxx/yyy/hello.wsgi` the script started to work. But I still have problems importing some modules (cStringIO for instance). Any ideas what may cause this? I tried to execute chcon for the whole env directory, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: This selinux tip is golden for those on CentOS.  I'm on 6.1 and followed [the famous video tutorial without luck](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6). I had success disabling selinux with `echo 0>/selinux/enforcing`