# how to give permission to apache to my folder in centos to access it

Tags: linux, apache, centos, python-2.6

How do i rectify this error in centos,

as i started the apache service by

```
service httpd start
```

it was up and running

i have given permission to this folder.

when i run

```
ls - l
drwxrwxr-x. 7 intel apache 4096 Apr 14 03:28 ux
```

in ux folder there was static folder, in static folder an images fodler is there.

when i am typing

```
127.0.0.1/images/404.png
```

I have run the

```
chmod 755 /home/intel/gopi/fodler
```

It is throwing me

```
 Forbidden:
 ou don't have permission to access /tmp/mobi.log on this server.
```

But, how can i fix this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod\_wsgi forbidden error on CentOS 5.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213649/mod-wsgi-forbidden-error-on-centos-5-7)

Comment: what i can't understand can you please elaborate it

Comment: possible duplicate is not  the issue